# shell ksh function parameter contains another function name to call

Tags: shell, error-handling, function-pointers, ksh

I am trying to write a generic function (say `holder`) - which will take the first parameter name as another function name (like `f1,f2,f3,f4...`) and calls them based on some condition. Like

---

```
#!/bin/ksh
function f1
{
echo "f1"
return 7
}

function f2
{
echo "f2"
return 8
}

function holder
{
fptr=$1
`${fptr}`
ret=$?
echo $ret
}

holder "f1"
holder "f2"
```

---

Now above sample works. However, sometimes the evaluation line `${fptr}` , strange failures occur with details of stack. I suspect the way I am calling the function might have some issues.Above code is a sample mock code, actual code contains complex `f1,f2` logic.

1. Is it possible to handle such kind of indirect invocation?
2. Is the "function calling" in holder class correct? or should it be handled in a separate way?

Comment: `holder f1` will first call `f1`, and then evaluates its output, resulting in `f1` being called twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to figure what causes sporadic failures in your case.  However, there are a couple of things that you might want to change:

1. You probably want to use `eval` instead of backticks.
2. You can refer to the function name using `$0`

Executing the modified code:

```
function f1 {
  echo $0
  return 7
}

function f2 {
  echo $0
  return 8
}

function holder {
  eval "$1"
  echo $?
}

holder "f1"
holder "f2"
```

returns:

```
f1
7
f2
8
```